# Got empty tables invertica after execute a file by vsql

Tags: vertica

Step by step scenario:

1. Start cmd from odcker
2. Run install.sh with list of files
3. sql file with schema loaded (I see tables)
4. sql with data alsoe excuted but no data present in tables.

But If I execute same file (!) by Intellij Idea that connected to same docker container where I run vsql - I got data

What is going on? How to debug/fix the situation?

install.sh file is:

```
vsql -d mydb -U dbadmin -h localhost  -f /dump/schema.sql
vsql -d mydb -U dbadmin -h localhost  -f /dump/jailer/vertica.sql
vsql -d mydb -U dbadmin -h localhost  -f /dump/data/my_table.sql
vsql -d mydb -U dbadmin -h localhost  -f /dump/data-patch.sql
```

Same output for manual `vsql -d mydb -U dbadmin -h localhost  -f /dump/jailer/vertica.sql` call:

```
Time: First fetch (1 row): 58.681 ms. All rows formatted: 58.766 ms
 OUTPUT
--------
     14
(1 row)
```

vertica.sql content:

```
Insert into mydb."public".atable(id, column) values
 (17, 'value'),
 (12, 'value');
```

IntelliJ output:

```
[2023-05-03 12:46:16] 852 row(s) affected in 7 sec, 881 ms
```

**Offtop**: somebody please add vsql tag [it already present on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vsql)

Answer (score 0):

Autocommit is [off by default](https://www.vertica.com/docs/9.3.x/HTML/Content/Authoring/ConnectingToVertica/vsql/AUTOCOMMIT.htm) in vertica. So adding `vsql -v AUTOCOMMIT=on` fixed the issue.